# JQGrid Inconsistencies with IE9

Tags: jqgrid

I am stumped. I am using JQGrid in IE9 and it doesn't behave like it does in other browsers. This is very easy to demonstrate. If you look at the Loading Data demo at http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html and select "Array Data" and look at the grid, in IE9 it looks different than it does in Chrome, Safari or Fox. First off, it has a horizontal scroll bar? and the notes column extends past the end of the grid. If you try and use the column resize bar between the Total and Notes column in IE9 there is a big offset in the column line. This does not happen in other browsers. If you move the checkbox column to the end of the grid and when a vertical scroll bar appears, it hides the checkbox column. This again happens only in IE9.
I am using the 4.4.3 version of JQGrid.
If anyone can shed some light if I am doing soemthing wrong or a workaround it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't see any difference between the look of the "Loading Data" / "Array Data" page of [the official jqGrid demo](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) in IE9 and other web browsers which I have (Chrome 24, Firefox 18, Opera 12.13).

The page from the demo "Loading Data" / "Array Data" are made for very very old version of jqGrid and the current usage of jqGrid in the way would be very bad style. Instead of that one should move the line which definition and initializing of `mydata` at the beginning of the code, One should add `data: mydata, gridview: true,`  options to the grid and add additionally either a pager (`pager` option or `toppager: true` option) or add `rowNum` with large enough value if one don't want to use any local paging of data. For example one could add `rowNum: 10000` option.

To remove unneeded empty space in the grid I would recommend you to use `height: "auto"` (or `height: "100%"`) or use alternatively `scrollOffset: 0` option.